World record for longest time of being Fleishig
Based on the discussions here: Where do the different traditions for hours of waiting between meat and milk come from?, what would be the world record for the longest time one can maintain their state of being Fleishig?
In other words, what is the theoretical maximum amount of days one can be Fleishig non-stop if they consistently consume meat every 6 hours, or based on the opinion they follow?
The furthest I can posit is 384 days before hitting Yom Kippur (see Jewish leap year). How I reached it:

There can be up to 385 days in a Jewish leap year, minus Yom Kippur bringing it down to 384. They would have to achieve this during a leap year.
It could be achieved by someone living during a time when Tisha B'av isn't observed (such as before the Beis HaMikdash was destroyed)
And ideally if this person lived before the Taanis of Esther was formed (such as before the story of Purim happened).
And before the 10th of Teves became a fast day.
And before Gedaliah was murdered so that there wouldn't be Tzom Gedaliah.
And either not be a Bechor, or else attend a Siyum Erev Pesach.
It would be ideal if this person would hold that they cannot eat dairy for 24 hours, like Mar Ukva's father did. Otherwise they would have to eat meat consistently sooner.

Based on these assumptions, the maximum time someone can maintain their state of Fleishig should be 384 days. Is there any way it can be longer than this? Such as if this person is weak and needs to eat meat on Yom Kippur?

You beat me to the punch with Mar Ukva's father. BTW I heard the story of some guys in Shana Alef in Israel who tried staying fleishig for a week. The yekke had a salami near his bed and set an alarm for every three hours. Of all the dumb things for college students to try, this one's relatively harmless ...

What's the point?

The point is to discover the theoretical limit!
